# Value returned from jQuery is always null when accessing it from codebehind in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, code-behind

My master page contains a menu which is dynamically created in `<ul><li><li><ul/>` format.

When I click on it, I want to pass its ID to codebehind for passing it into base class for its permission. But am getting value from jQuery always null in codebehind - but am getting value in jQuery function.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#nav li').click(function () {      
               debugger;
                var vals = $(this).text();  
                document.getElementById('hdnForLabel').value = vals ;               
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

This page load am using in Master Page.

```csharp
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       

            GetMenus();
            string pageids = hdnForLabel.Value;
            BasePage BasePage = new BasePage();
            BasePage.LoadSettings(pageids );            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the ID of your rendered hidden control is really 'hdnForLabel'? It might be something along the line of 'ctl00_hdnForLabel'. 
You could use jQuery to check if the value has been set on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav li').click(function () {      
           debugger;
            var vals = $(this).text();  
            document.getElementById('hdnForLabel').value = vals ;               
            alert( "Value: " + $("#hdnForLabel").val());
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Please note that a value set for hdnForLabel.Value is only available when the page is sent back to the server via postback

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
        GetMenus();
        if (IsPostBack) {
          string pageids = hdnForLabel.Value;
          BasePage BasePage = new BasePage();
          BasePage.LoadSettings(pageids );            
        }
}
```

Comment: i doubled checked it...id for hidden control is same only...and it is in postback only am setting its value in jquery

Comment: have you checked the posted values using something like FireBug in Firefox to check if the hidden value is sent to the server?